# Adding a ImageView from a resource to a LinearLayout in the javacode

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am new to programming Android but have some experience with Java, albeit still pretty inexperienced.

I'll firstly post the XML document so it's easier to describe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#4E2FEB">
    </LinearLayout>


    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#E01F39" >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/card_tray"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I want to add ImageView's to the HorizontalScrollView in java code. Here is the code i got so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.card_tray);

        l.addView((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xo_1));
        l.addView((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xo_2));
}
```

Here is the other .xml file i have that contains the ImageView views i'm trying to refer to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/xo_1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" 
                android:src="@drawable/xo_1" /> 

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/xo_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" 
                android:src="@drawable/xo_2" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

When i try to run it on my Tablet using Eclipse it crashes with the usual 'App is not responding' message.

**EDIT:**
Here is the LogCat output.

> 03-30 01:38:13.053: D/AndroidRuntime(29659): Shutting down VM 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: W/dalvikvm(29659): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41f0b2a0) 03-30 01:38:13.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-30 01:38:13.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29659): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity ComponentInfo{kpapps.testapp/kpapps.testapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-30 01:38:13.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-30 01:38:13.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-30 01:38:13.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-30 01:38:13.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29659): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3481) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3464) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   kpapps.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188) 03-30
>   01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   03-30 01:38:13.053: E/AndroidRuntime(29659):  ... 11 more

**EDIT:** As per requested. Line 22 of MainActivity.java

```
l.addView((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xo_1));
```

**EDIT:**

### Revision

I changed the java code to;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.card_tray);

        View cards = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.skill_cards, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cards.findViewById(R.id.xo_1);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)cards.findViewById(R.id.xo_2);

        l.addView(imageView);
        l.addView(imageView2);
}
```

But it still crashes just with a different error. Here is the new LogCat;

> 03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{kpapps.testapp/kpapps.testapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-30 02:10:31.833:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-30 02:10:31.833:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-30 02:10:31.833:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4978): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first. 03-30 02:10:31.833:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3672) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3543) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3488) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3464) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   kpapps.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188) 03-30
>   02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   03-30 02:10:31.833: E/AndroidRuntime(4978):   ... 11 more

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Good point. I'll add that. To be honest i'm not sure i don't really understand how to LogCat works but when i run it on my tablet it crashes with the usual message.

Comment: There is no usual message. Filtering by "error" you should see "Fatal Exception" followed by a reason such as "Null Pointer Exception" or in your case likely "Class Cast Exception". After that you will somewhere see a line that references your package with a file name of yours and a line where the exception occurred. That is where you should start. If you are confused by that then feel free to copy/paste the logcat output in your post and we can give better help. No worries, logcat is confusing until you are used to how it works

Comment: By the looks of it the addView() method is throwing a NullPointerException but i'mm post the LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` will only look inside the layout set in `setContentView()`. 
The imageviews `xo_1` and `xo_2` are in a different layout, therefore `findViewById(R.id.xo_1)` will always be null.

You have to inflate your second layout first:

```
View secondLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.second_layout, null, false);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) secondLayout.findViewById(R.id.xo_1));
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) secondLayout.findViewById(R.id.xo_2));
l.addView(imageView);
l.addView(imageView2);
```

If you're looking for a dynamic way of adding your `ImageView`s, you don't need to define them in an xml layout.

You can add them programmatically:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.xo_1);
// etc...
l.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
```

Comment: When i do the code you suggested it still crashes but i get a different exception. 

'03-30 02:00:44.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3461): Caused by:         java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.'

Should i update my post? It's just getting very long.

Comment: Are you using `null` in the second argument of `inflate()` ?

Comment: Well this is really an odd way of adding ImageViews. We usually either include them in the first layout or add them dynamically. And I'm not on my dev pc so I'm writing this from the top of my head. I think since the ImageViews have a parent which is the linearlayout, you have to remove them first. So try calling `secondLayout.removeView(imageView);` and `secondLayout.removeView(imageView2)` before l.addView().

Comment: I had to cast the layout to ViewGroup since removeView() is a method of ViewGroup. But this did work. Maybe doing it dynamically might have been easier but since i knew exactly how i wanted them to look but only add them later on not at the start i though defining in xml would save some time and space but perhaps i was wrong. Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK, one last thing I had forgotten. If we add 'false' to the inflate() method, the views won't be attached to the linearlayout. So there wouldn't be any need to call `removeView()`.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be an exact answer until we see the logcat but you can try something like

```
 LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.card_tray);  
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xo_1));
 ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xo_2));
 l.addView(imageView);
 l.addView(imageView2);
```

This should add those two `ImageView`s to the `LinearLayout` you declared. I hope this helps. If not, then please copy and paste the logcat errors as I described.

**Note**

You can only work with the `Layout` that has been inflated but I see you are working with two different `Layouts`. You are probably trying to access a `View` that isn't in the `layout` you inflated here `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: This line `at kpapps.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 03-30 01:38:13.053` means there is a `null` value at line 22 of `MainActivity`. Please edit your post with this line

Comment: I'm guessing that `(R.id.xo_1)` is not in your `activity_main` `layout` which you inflate with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. If you want to use `Views` in that other `layout` then you need to use a `layout inflater` before you can access its `Views`